# Surface to Tetrahedral Mesh

Tags: geometry, triangulation, finite-element-analysis

Does anybody know a way to generate a tetrahedral mesh from the surface of a geometrc object?

I only got 1D and 2D elements (nodes, lines, triangles) in 3D space and want to generate tetrahedrons out of it.

I know that it's not always possible, but I think it should be possible if the lines and triangles are building a valid surface.

Thanks for any hint....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at

> Shewchuk, Jonathan Richard. "Constrained Delaunay Tetrahedralizations and Provably Good Boundary Recovery." *IMR*. 2002.
>   ([PDF download](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e54/6556fe79e28a87dc08fc3d722c544e0ad7ea.pdf).)

In order to get these CDT's, you might have to alter your surface triangulation.

> "However, boundary conformity can always be enforced by judicious insertion of additional
>   vertices, combined with CDTs."

Many subsequent algorithms have been developed and implemented based on CDT's.

Comment: That really helped me. Thank you very much!